# Can I send Data to Controller after AJAX Success in PHP Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to send "data" to the controller that came from controller to success of ajax and its a different controller function then the first one.

```
 $.ajax({
    url :'<?= base_url('Content/get_thumb') ?>',  // Controller URL
    type : 'POST',
    data : formData,
    async : false,
    cache : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    success : function(data) {   
        $('#video_thumb').show();
        $('#thumb_image').html('<img src="' + data + '" style="margin-top:57px;" /> ');
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes you can, have you considered adding another ajax call in your success function

Comment: What have you tried? Since this is very well possible by just writing a second ajax call in the `success` part.

Comment: Actually i'm new to ajax so let me try that.i didn't know about that.btw thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, just after success function you can run another function that will send data back to your controller.

```
$.ajax({
    url :'Controller URL',  // Controller URL
    type : 'POST',
    data : formData,
    async : false,
    cache : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    success : function(data) {   
        $('#video_thumb').show();
        $('#thumb_image').html('<img src="' + data + '" style="margin-top:57px;" /> ');
        function_name(data); //run another function to send data.
    }
});
```

The function to run on sucess

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function function_name(DataToSend) {
        $.ajax({
        url :'<?= base_url('Content/get_thumb') ?>',  // Controller URL
        type : 'POST',
        data : DataToSend,
        success : function(response) {   
            //Do what needs to be done
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: how can i get success "data" of 1st ajax into the second ajax?

Comment: @Scarface pass the data as argument in the second function as I did in the post